# What does the "+½ hit point" favored class bonus mean?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, paladin, halfling

I want to blame this on lack of sleep, but this is just making no sense to me. I'm building a level 10 halfling paladin. It's to replace a PC whose player had to leave for a bit for work, and didn't leave me his sheet.

The [favored class bonus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/paladin#TOC-Favored-Class-Bonuses) for a halfling paladin (along with a gnome or dwarf paladin) is:

> Add +½ hit point to the paladin's lay on hands ability (whether using it to heal or harm).

What does this actually mean?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Every second time you take that favored class bonus option, you gain +1 to the healing that paladin does every time he uses his lay on hands class ability (or the harm he does to an undead creature if he lays hands on it).

At 10th level, the paladin probably has quite a few uses of lay on hands daily, so boosting the healing from each use by +5 (assuming you take that option every level for 10 levels) isn't bad.

A full explanation of how exactly lay on hands works is outside the scope of the this answer, I'm hoping it's just the favored class bonus you're unsure about.

Comment: yes... thank you. The way I was reading it, it sounded like they were getting 1.5 the health back every time I took the bonus.

Comment: @Maldrek If this answer fully answers your question, remember to accept it. If it doesn't quite answer it, feel free to wait for more. You can always change the accepted answer later if a better one comes along.

Comment: Well, that said, there's no harm in waiting a day or two to accept an answer even if an existing useful one is present. We'd just prefer that questions which have a great answer the asker's happy with get that answer marked as accepted, sooner or later, in whatever cases such an answer actually exists.